# mongoose how to filter array of objectIds in document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, filter

How can i filter 'array' of object ids inside of mongo document, so that it doesn't include "60ba4ca6f170dsfa234", and will update document. Thank you!

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60bfdae011abd61c3eec"),
    "array" : [ 
        ObjectId("60ba4ca6f170dsfa234"), 
        ObjectId("60bd240df30ead9293d")

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `$project` pipeline stage with the `$filter` option.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "array": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$array",
          "cond": {
            "$ne": [
              "$$this",
              {  // <-- Ignore this block and pass value directly you are passing `ObjectId` directly drom driver and conversion from string is not required
                "$toObjectId": "60407d54a8204c86a62bf231"  // <-- ObjectId you want to be removed from the array
              }
            ],
          },
        }
      },
    },
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",  // <-- Change to source collection name where the changes has to be updated
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "merge",
    },
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u98WFWt2p2h)